# Erro no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ao tentar acessar um *Wordpress*, o seguinte erro aparece:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/usuario143/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra//includes/panel/theme-panel.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php') in
>   /home/usuario143/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/ocean-extra.php
>   on line 112

Alguém já se deparou com este erro.

Comment: Isso é um erro no seu plugin,  conseguer ver se seu theme ta pedindo update, se sim faça e veja se resolve

Comment: não consigo, não deixa nem eu entrar no wp-admin... apareceo erro

Comment: não será ausencia do php5.6?]

Comment: Se tiver faltando o php não vai rodar

Comment: atualizei para o 5.6  nao resolveu

Comment: Baixe o plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ocean-extra/ e envie os arquivos via FTP.

Comment: deletei tudo, atualizei o php para 5.6 novamente e configurou o .htaccess para wordpress... subi e funcionou